# How to install gnumeric on Oracle Linux 6?

Tags: software-installation, yum, oracle-linux

Many blogs suggest `sudo yum install gnumeric` and `sudo yum install gnumeric.x86_64`, but to me both are giving the following message:

> Loaded plugins: security, ulninfo 
>   Setting up Install Process 
>   No package gnumeric available. 
>   Error: Nothing to do

I also tried to download and install **gnumeric-1.12.38**, **goffice-0.10.38**, **itstool-2.0.4**, **rarian-0.8.1** but failed as every module has dependencies and those dependencies also have further dependencies.

How can I install these packages?

Comment: Not sure about Oracle Linux 6, but gnumeric is shipped with the EPEL repository: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL. Add that repo and install gnumeric with yum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thomas's comment pointed me in the right direction.

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm 
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install gnumeric
```

installed the gnumeric.